# Django: How to get the current user id in viewsets

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

This is my view using rest_framwork viewsets. I am a beginner at this please help.

These are my serializer classes.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from . import models

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'password')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True, 'required': True}}
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
        Token.objects.create(user=user)
        return user

class ToDoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.ToDo
        fields = ('id', 'user', 'title', 'date')
```

These are my viewset classes.

```
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny, IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework import viewsets
from . import serializers, models
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication

# Create your views here.

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.UserSerializer
    permission_classes = (AllowAny, )

class ToDoViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.ToDo.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.ToDoSerializer
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication, )
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )
```

I didn't quite understand how to filter out based on the current user who is logged in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.UserSerializer
    permission_classes = (AllowAny, )

    def get_queryset(self):                                            # added string
        return super().get_queryset().filter(id=self.request.user.id)   # added string


class ToDoViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.ToDo.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.ToDoSerializer
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication, )
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )

    def get_queryset(self):                                            # added string
        return super().get_queryset().filter(user=self.request.user)   # added string
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! It actually worked!

Comment: You can validate my answer as a solution

Answer (score 1):

You can get the current user from request.
Please keep in mind that you will get anonymous user if user is not authenticated and viewset permission is open for all.
Also you can pass the request.user instance in get serializer context and use in serializers also.

Instead of
`queryset = models.ToDo.objects.filter(user=1)`

override get_quesryset method and filter query using self.request.user

```
def get_queryset(self): 
    return models.ToDo.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

Comment: I didn't quite get it. Please help.

Comment: You need to override get_queryset method of viewset